# MySQL: I need to know if articles that have been stored in a compartment, were withdrawn within 1 week after storing

Tags: mysql, date

I have the following table called **operation** (there are more columns, but these are the relevant ones):

```
idOperation articleNumber articleLabel   userIdentifier userName dateTime            actionName   quantity
----------- ------------- -------------- -------------- -------- ------------------- ----------   --------
1           Article_01    Articletext_01 00001          Max      2022-12-09 07:22:28 Store        1 
2           Article_02    Articletext_02 00002          John     2022-12-09 07:22:50 Store        1
3           Article_01    Articletext_01 00003          Jane     2022-12-11 09:31:47 Withdraw     1
```

Article_01 is stored on 2022-12-09 and withdrawn on 2022-12-11, so everything is fine.
Article_02 is stored on 2022-12-09 and not withdrawn within 1 week, so i want to know.

I want to compare two different rows with the same `articleNumber`, if there is a store and a withdraw operation within 1 week of each other.

I don't have any idea how to start my command.

```
SELECT idOperation, articleNumber, articleLabel, userIdentifier, userName, dateTime, actionName, quantity 
FROM operation
WHERE actionName IN ("Store", "Withdraw");
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: One place you say you want where it is within a week, another you say you want where it is not.  If the latter, say if you also want where there is no withdraw after.  Also, can there be multiple stores without a withdraw between (for the same article)?  If so what?  Finally, you need to show what your desired output is.

Comment: Isn't this the same as saying if most recent entry is store then you are interested and how long ago it was stored is not relevant? and if it is relevant was it stored within now() - 7 days?

Comment: @P.Salmon
Yes, you are right, this is a much better explanation than i provided.

Comment: @ysth There can only be one store for an article followed by a withdrawal. I want to know, if an article has been stored, whether an withdrawal has occurred within 1 week or not if the article has been withdrawn, everything is fine. If it has not been withdrawn, i want to get that information in a result-set. i don't quite know, how my desired output can even look like.